# Can you transfer Steam games from one Ubuntu Laptop to another?

Tags: 14.04, games, steam, transfer

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261273/is-there-a-way-to-import-my-steam-games-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu) is about importing steam games from Windows to Ubuntu so is similar but I don't think a duplicate.

A little on my situation, I have an old laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 and have Steam installed with some games downloaded or part-downloaded. I've got a new laptop also running ubuntu 14.04 and have installed steam. I have not yet opened steam. If it makes any difference my old laptop only has one HDD whereas my new machine has / on a SSD and /home on a HDD and user name is the same on both.

Is there an easy way to transfer my steam game files from my old laptop to my new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have setup separate libraries, Steam on Linux stores all the games in the `.local/share/Steam/SteamApps`, which is the equivalent of the Windows Steam client's SteamApps folder. So just copy this folder.